# Meaning of cores and logical processors in intel icore

Tags: cpu, intel, multicore

In my laptop I see two terms under Task Manager -> Performance -> CPU  ==> `Cores` and `Logical Processors`.

**The below is the screen shot of the same:**

[image]

My laptop is having intel core i3.

Can anyone help me understand what is `core` and what is `logical processors`.

Comment: Voted to migrate to superuser.com, where this is on-topic.  (That's separate from voting to close as "might be on-topic on superuser")

Answer (score 1):

I would consider this thread as offtopic.

They are different levels of abstractions. At higher level we have one physical CPU (one physical socket). One CPU is divided into two physical cores. Each core has its own circuits to execute instructions and its own L1 and L2 caches. That is, two cores may work simultaneously, because cores are independant (for the most part). However, they have shared connections via shared L3 cache. One CPU unit have two L1 caches, two L2 caches and one L3 cache shared between both cores.

Intel uses Hyper-Threading (HT) technology to reuse processing units/circuits in more effective ways. Say, each core may have one processing circuit to add two numbers and one processing circuit to perform two number multiplication. If you need to add two numbers and multiply another two numbers, you can perform these operations simultaneously on the same core. This is why Windows OS threats each core with HT technology as two logical processors.

However this is not a real parallelism, because if you need to add multiple different numbers, you cannot do that on the same core, because there is only one addition circuit in the core. In certain cases instruction queue may be optimized to utilize different processing circuits on the same core simultaneously, but in other cases it can't be optimizied due to execution plan.

Comment: I know it is off topic, I used this as last resort to get my doubts clear. I did listen video on youtube and other online materials, however doubt persisted. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: I don't think this explains very well how HT exposes more instruction-level parallelism for out-of-order execution.  The OP's Skylake CPU can already exploit the instruction-level parallelism in a single-threaded sequence of independent multiply and add instructions, since it's a superscalar out-of-order core that can run up to 4 `add` instructions per clock if their input operands are ready.  Or a multiply and 3 `add`s.  (But only one `add` per clock if the input of one comes from the output of the previous: `add` has 1 cycle latency, but 4 per clock throughput).

Comment: re: off-topic: vote to migrate to superuser, like I did.